# How to avoid two arduino components using the same digital PIN

Tags: pins, tft

I'm trying to build an Arduino project where it involves a TFT and an ethernet W5500 component.

Here's the [project](https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-and-ENC28J60-Ethernet-Controller-320x480-T/) I want to build to learn Arduino. However I wanted to change the board that already has an ethernet PoE [here](https://robotdyn.com/leonardo-eth-v2-with-atmega32u4-ethernet-w5500-arduino-compatible-board.html). The TFT I plan to use is a [shield](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1947). It seems that pin D10 are being used by both components.
Is it possible through software to use a different Digital pin through software for either the board or the TFT display?  I have read where users are cutting traces and using jumper wires - would that be required in my case? I am planning on using SPI pins if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - let me edit.  I forgot to mention the TFT I plan on using is a shield. The W5500 mention in my link is built-in to the board and uses CS10.

Comment: Yes you can, but you will need to modify your TFT screen shield to disconnect pin 10 and route it to an unused pin.

Comment: Just connect the pin that would go into `D10` to an unused pin with a cable. When defining `TFT_CS`, change the `10` simply to the pin you used.